# zypper: how to list all active package repos?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

How can I show all active package repos with `zypper`?

I need the output for a check script.

I know how to list them all. But I would like to avoid to parse this output with a regex:

```
foo-work:~ # LANG=C zypper lr
# | Alias                             | Name                          | Enabled | Refresh
--+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+---------+--------
1 | openSUSE 12.3 FOO-BAR           | openSUSE 12.3 FOO-BAR           | Yes     | Yes    
2 | openSUSE 12.3 FOO-BAR Test      | openSUSE 12.3 FOO-BAR Test      | Yes     | No     
3 | openSUSE-12.3 Updates (FOO-BAR) | openSUSE-12.3 Updates (FOO-BAR) | Yes     | Yes    
4 | openSUSE-12.3-Non-Oss (FOO-BAR) | openSUSE-12.3-Non-Oss (FOO-BAR) | Yes     | No     
5 | openSUSE-12.3-Oss (FOO-BAR)     | openSUSE-12.3-Oss (FOO-BAR)     | Yes     | No
```

Comment: `man zypper` is helpful, as usual.

Comment: @Sven I prefer my favorite search engine. If this does not provide an answer, then I will ask a question. This has the big benefit that my team mates (or other people) will find the answer the next time faster (without reading the man page).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for the `-E, --show-enabled-only` flag to only show enabled repositories, or the `-e -` , `--export -` to get the listing in the repository definition format that allows for much easier parsing?

```
zypper lr -E -e - |grep name=
```

Comment: On SuSE 12.3 the `-E` option exists, but does not filter the disabled repos. But I can do this myself. Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

This will print only the enabled repositories on SuSE:

```
zypper lr | awk -F'|' '{gsub(/ /, "", $0); if($4=="Yes") print $2}'
```

The gsub call is only there to remove the leading and trailing blanks.